# How to save predicted regression values inside a for loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, logistic-regression

I'm trying to use statsmodels to run separate logistic regressions for each "group" in a pandas dataframe and save the predicted probabilities for each observations (row).  Each "group" represents about 2500 respondents or observations; I would like to get the predicted probability for each respondent - similar to how with SPSS you can "save" predicted probabilities when running a logistic regression.

I've read what others have attempted, but nothing seems to work.  I'm using SPSS to check that the looping operation in Python is working correctly - the predicted probabilities should be the same (SPSS has a split function which makes this really easy).

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from statsmodels.formula.api import logit

    df = pd.read_csv('test_data.csv')

    for cat in df['Brand'].unique():
        df_slice = df[df.Brand == cat]
        est = logit('binary ~ var_1', df_slice)
        est_result = est.fit()
        pred = est_result.predict(df)
        print(est_result.summary())
        df['pred'] = pred
```

The model summaries are correct (est_result.summary()) and match SPSS exactly.  However, the saved predicted values do not match at all.  I cannot seem to understand how to get it to work correctly.
Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: The dataframe has three columns: Brand (categorical), var_1 (which is continuous variable), and binary (which is the dependent variable).  There are about 2500 observations per brand, and each brand needs its own model

Comment: here is a link to my share drive which contains a sample data file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UsAJeXp7cceeUuQoy7dszEnXOx7ncont

Comment: not sure why this was down-voted, as I see others have been asking the same question...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in a really un-pythonic kind of way.  I hope someone can improve this code.  The probabilities now match exactly what SPSS produces when you split the file by group, and run individual regressions by group.

```
result =[]
for cat in df['Brand'].unique():
   df_slice = df[df.Brand == cat]
   est = logit('binary ~ var_1', df_slice)
   est_result = est.fit()
   pred = est_result.predict(df_slice)
   results.append(pred)
   # print(est_result.summary())

n = len(df['Brand'].unique())
r = pd.DataFrame(results) #put the results into a dataframe 
rt = r.T #tranpose the dataframe
r_small = rt[rt.columns[-n:]] #remove all but the last n columns, n = number of categories
r_new = r_small.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0] #merge the n columns and remove the NaNs
r_new #show us

df['predicted'] = r_new # combine the r_new array with the original dataframe
df #show us.
```